# Rails variable in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("change","#status",function() {
    var id_booking = $(this).attr('class')
    data = $('option:selected',this).text().toLowerCase()
    $.ajax({
      type: "PATCH",
      url: "<%= room_booking_path(room_id: 1, id: 1, status: data) %>",
    })
  })
```

Error: undefined local variable or method `data' for #ActionView::Base:0x00000000017430

How can i pass "data" variable to <%= %> tag. Thank you!

Comment: Relevant: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429)

Answer (score 0):

You try this way.

```
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
   $(document).on("change","#status",function() {
    var id_booking = $(this).attr('class')
    data = $('option:selected',this).text().toLowerCase()
    $.ajax({
      type: "PATCH",
      url: "<%= room_booking_path(room_id: 1, id: 1, status: data) %>",
    })
  })
  <% end %>
```